# How to push JSON data in two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get a structure like

```
var tableData= [
  ['Hfbj'],
  ['Hygh'],
  [6],
  ['mayur'],
  [2563458952]
]
```

Here is my JSON data:

```
data:{
  "address"': "Hfbj"
  "id": 6
  "landmark": "Hygh"
  "name": "mayur"
  "phone": 2563458952
  "title": "aaa"
}
```

I am using [react-native-table-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component) in which that type of structure needed. For that, I am doing the following but it showing `data.map is not function and undefined`.

```
let newdata = this.state.tableData[0].push(
  [responseJson.data.title],
  [responseJson.data.title]
);

this.setState({
  tableData: newdata
});
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: That's _not_ [JSON](http://json.org). [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Please add the "logic" that determines the expected output? Why are some values missing? Where is `Hygh` coming from?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want one value per row in your table? Because that's what this kind of format would produce, according to the docs you linked.

Comment: yes one value per row @Jeto

Comment: Updates question now @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/map):

```js
var reponseJson = {
  data: {
    "address": "Hfbj",
    "id": 6,
    "landmark": "Hygh",
    "name": "mayur",
    "phone": 2563458952,
    "title": "aaa"
  }
};

var newData = Object.values(reponseJson.data)
  .map(item => [item]);

console.log(newData);
```

Note that I used the `responseJson` name to match your question, but as @Andreas pointed out, this is an object, not JSON.

If you need only certain columns (as requested in the comments below), use `Object.keys` and `Array.filter` on them before rebuilding the array:

```js
var reponseJson = {
  data: {
    "address": "Hfbj",
    "id": 6,
    "landmark": "Hygh",
    "name": "mayur",
    "phone": 2563458952,
    "title": "aaa"
  }
};

var keysToKeep = ['address', 'landmark', 'title'];

var newData = Object.keys(reponseJson.data)
  .filter(key => keysToKeep.includes(key))
  .map(key => [reponseJson.data[key]]);

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Is it any way to get array of only for some values from `responseJson.data`, Not all.

Answer (score 1):

`.map` Is for arrays, whereas your `responseJson.data` is an Object. To get turn that Object into an array of its values you can do `Object.values(responseJson.data)`